# How to draw route using multiple geopoints?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing an android application for Map activity.

I am using Location listener for getting location updates. After updating location i am saving those updated latitude and longitude values in database.

I am able draw Route path From Source to destination using source latitude, longitude and destination latitude, longitude values. But using multiple latitude and longitude values of database at a time i want to draw the route path. I am using my **RoutePath.java** class to draw the route path for **multiple latitudes and longitudes**.Using those list of latitudes and longitudes i am able to draw the path, but it shows point to point stright line not shows the route path. See the below image...

[image]

If you observe carefully some points are on the route and some points are outside of route path. See again below image with full zooming...

[image]

Please help me if anyone knows the solution for this problem...

**RoutePath.java:**

```
public class RoutePath extends Overlay {

    private int _pathColor;
    private final List<GeoPoint> _points;
    private boolean _drawStartEnd;

    public RoutePath(List<GeoPoint> points) {
        this(points, Color.RED, true);
    }

    public RoutePath(List<GeoPoint> points, int pathColor,
            boolean drawStartEnd) {
        _points = points;
        _pathColor = pathColor;
        _drawStartEnd = drawStartEnd;
    }

    private void drawOval(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, Point point) {
        Paint ovalPaint = new Paint(paint);
        ovalPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        ovalPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        int _radius = 6;
        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - _radius, point.y - _radius, point.x
                + _radius, point.y + _radius);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, ovalPaint);
    }

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false && _points != null) {
            Point startPoint = null, endPoint = null;
            Path path = new Path();
            // We are creating the path
            for (int i = 0; i < _points.size(); i++) {
                GeoPoint gPointA = _points.get(i);
                Point pointA = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(gPointA, pointA);
                if (i == 0) { // This is the start point
                    startPoint = pointA;
                    path.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
                } else {
                    if (i == _points.size() - 1)// This is the end point
                        endPoint = pointA;
                    path.lineTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
                }
            }

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(_pathColor);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAlpha(90);
            if (getDrawStartEnd()) {
                if (startPoint != null) {
                    drawOval(canvas, paint, startPoint);
                }
                if (endPoint != null) {
                    drawOval(canvas, paint, endPoint);
                }
            }
            if (!path.isEmpty())
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
    }

    public boolean getDrawStartEnd() {
        return _drawStartEnd;
    }

    public void setDrawStartEnd(boolean markStartEnd) {
        _drawStartEnd = markStartEnd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question but is this what you are looking for? https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Comment: Yes am doing this way of stright line. But i want to draw the route path not stright line as showing above link

Answer (score 0):

You got Straight line because the the GeoPoints are like that only..... means if you have a complete route paths then it will show according to your Geopoints....It all depends on GeoPoints.!